# Typescript promisfy all satisfied functions with proper param type

Tags: typescript, promise, generic-programming, type-constraints

I am working on a codebase with lots of asynchronous api involving `success` options in their params, like

```js
declare function foo(_: { 
  success?: (_: string) => void, 
  fail?: () => void, 
}): void

declare function bar(_: { 
  success?: (_: string) => void, 
  fail?: () => void, 
  src?: string
}): void

declare function baz(_: {
 success?: (_: string) => void, 
 fail?: () => void, 
 expired: number 
}): void

declare function foobar(_: { 
  success?: (_: string) => void, 
  fail?: () => void, 
  token: string, 
  state: boolean 
}): void
```

i want to promisefy all of them with below code

```js
interface Cont<R> {
  fail?: () => void
  success?: (_: R) => void
}

interface Suspendable<O> {
  (option: O): void
}

function suspend<R, O extends Cont<R>>(fn: Suspendable<O>) { 
  return async (opt: Omit<Omit<O, "success">, "fail">) => await new Promise<R>((resolve, _) => fn({
    ...opt,
    success: it => resolve(it),
    fail: ()=> resolve(undefined)
  }  as O )) // if any chance, I'd like to omit the `as O` but forgive it for now
}


(async () => {
  let _foo = await suspend(foo)({}) // good 
  let _bar = await suspend(bar)({}) // good
  let _baz = await suspend(baz)/* compile error here */ ({ expired: 100})
})()
```

did I missed some goodies in typescript to help me capture the real type of the `O` in the `fn` param so that I can constraint the params nicely and pass the compiler error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways I can think of to go here.  The first is to give up on having two type parameters, and just infer `O` and compute `R` from it:

```
function suspend<O extends Cont<any>>(fn: Suspendable<O>) {
  return async (opt: Omit<O, "success" | "fail">) =>
    await new Promise<Parameters<Exclude<O["success"], undefined>>[0]>(
      (resolve, _) => fn({
        ...opt,
        success: it => resolve(it),
        fail: () => resolve(undefined)
      } as O));
}
```

The computation for `R` is the unfortunate-looking `Parameters<Exclude<O["success"], undefined>>[0]`.  Now the following compiles with no error:

```
(async () => {
  let _foo = await suspend(foo)({})
  let _bar = await suspend(bar)({})
  let _baz = await suspend(baz)({ expired: 2 })
})()
```

The error about `O` you get if you don't assert `as O` is a good one; it's possible that `fn()`'s argument has `success` or `fail` properties that are narrower than those specified in `Cont<any>`:

```
declare function hmm(opt: {
  success?: (_: unknown) => void,
  fail?: () => string // narrower than specified in Cont<any>
}): void;
suspend(hmm);
```

And since you are calling `fn()` with an arg having hand-rolled `success` and `fail` methods, you can't guarantee that it will behave as `fn()` expects.  So I think you'll need to assert and move on.

---

The other way you can go is to keep two type parameters, and rely on the fact that `success` and `fail` are optional methods to make it work:

```
function suspend2<O, R>(fn: Suspendable<O & Cont<R>>) {
  return async (opt: O) =>
    await new Promise<R>(
      (resolve, _) => fn({
        ...opt,
        success: (it: R) => resolve(it),
        fail: () => resolve(undefined)
      }));
}

Here we are inferring both `O` and `R` from an argument `fn` of type `Suspendable<O & Cont<R>>`.  Ideally this would automatically yield the right `R` as well as an `O` object type that doesn't include `success` or `fail` methods.  But what happens is that you'll get the right `R` (yay) but the value of `O` will be the full object type including the `success` and `fail` methods (boo).
```

At least now though you don't need type assertions like `as O`, since you are passing in a value of type `O & Cont<R>`.

The following still works as desired:

```
(async () => {
  let _foo = await suspend2(foo)({})
  let _bar = await suspend2(bar)({})
  let _baz = await suspend2(baz)({ expired: 2 })
})()
```

but only because `O` doesn't require `fail` or `success` properties.

---

Anyway, hope one of those helps you; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwAoB9ALngG8BYAKHngGdkwwRHGB+C0ixjGFlQBzAJTwAvAD54ANxxZgAGjoNEULBG7wi46XIXK6AX1EV5iunVCRYCFOmx54AI1i8qqpizYdtH-kERPRkLI3okDS0eEINFFQjGGDBtQKFhEzM44CtaG2g4JDRMXHw3AC8PGkSfdi4eciYBdNiwhLUo-1bDdvgQAA8AByw4YApUZABbFxAYTPNDXPy7IsdSghw3GCqvZlY6-0a04MlQnq91TS7T7N6MHABrEFQ+ZpFe-igMEAoXQggQFBUPNsrkhN8YOo2PAAMJ4DAAHgASjJqh0rjEbmFdrU-A0KEjupZaMYwagIVCEABlZCMQbPYBQFwAhEAeVRXiIOEGThe8FZWWxJNyDhKzmYdIZbL6-W+qGAjFh8IRQIAnlIpEREHyaZL5UyWezxGj4HAMMgYPgoIxVegdNyMBRWZMsIjWUp4AAiPa+Rie+AAHy9lwgnqkIS8DCgAHcNBh4KgQNH4AAFGA4F2MEAIlOwKCTEAQxgIgCi-UgyFAbIA2t7cX6ALoetCgRBCEDADXVgAMDc1kYYOjgjBwEFkIA9JFi2qIJsHg4AdEuHb15wwfXUKK6bsPR+OiK7RKu1yHMfpd2OQEQWyA24ngKIBwxjPBrfzRKIANwmXJEa22sAdFiE0AXjEhEEISRX1jbcJXpeUtUIURZ1MLxQPgEgtigmM428PVgCILZkMoVCInQzCoHKbCYPjOCGUIyjiJlYZRgoAAmeBSNMXQlnAAp7GKXl4AAC0mSYuR5CgTQ3PEdEaNAHlQHBo1QIlwnRaIgJuY4MhJQVDG-Wg6IQ0TJi-XI6FFITjOANi2Q9FEtR1Wl4MZZls1ZeAADIlXJZENWNLwzQtK0bTtCTHXfU4Bxw7dE2TNMMywLN-KIJ8h3YPcJww6dUFndKGCXBcVwK7x9g4HhXQJWIL33Q9j3nU8tPPTLL2veVb3bB90tMczhVoOg-zCwDdBuEDCwwiCcGo3CbLYxCcGI0iGHIrCJGg2aXIZeaiJQx8yImiiqPW2LaK2+UdsY2dmJGDt2M4-buP2uggA)